# Creating a watchdog log when publishing status changes on my own ContentEntityBase

Tags: 8, entities

I have a hierarchy of Entities derived from ContentEntityBase. Now I want to create a log when the publishing status ( = status field) changes.

What is the best method to override/implement for this purpose? In the Entity that extends ContentEntityBase or in the Form that extends ContentEntityForm?

Or somewhere else? I don't want to use a hook!

Thanks. Rainer.

Comment: Just a quick note: please use "extends" instead of derived. That's the right word in OO world.

Comment: "extends" is prevelant as a term because a few popular languages (java/php/etc) use it @ssibal; "derived" is also very commonly used when talking about inheritance, possibly even more so in my experience. There's no technical/conventional reason to use one over the other, they mean the same thing. https://www.techopedia.com/definition/3780/derived-class for example

Comment: Okey! I agree. I was too subjective! For me "extends" is more accurate and commonly used in php language for inheritance!

Comment: Did you try rules module?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to go for hooks (maybe events), **hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update**. You can find more about it in details [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update/8.2.x).

You only have to check if "status" field is being changed after update, and using the logging factory to put it into logs. This is also "form" independent (means it will run each time when entity gets updated), which is more general approach, and better for your system (more consistency).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks ssibal, with your hint I found an answer. In the hook page on drupal.org I found the dirty fact: "Get the original entity object from $entity->original."

So I implemented the hook, set a breakpoint and found that stack:

```
proreos/preosanwalt/preosanwalt.module.preosanwalt_anwalt_entity_update(): lineno 110   
proreos/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleHandler.php.call_user_func_array:{proreos/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleHandler.php:402}(): lineno 402  
proreos/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleHandler.php.Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAll(): lineno 402   
proreos/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php.Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->invokeHook(): lineno 167    
proreos/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityStorageBase.php.Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->invokeHook(): lineno 418  
proreos/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php.Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->doPostSave(): lineno 470    
proreos/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityStorageBase.php.Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->doPostSave(): lineno 304  
proreos/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php.Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->save(): lineno 395  
proreos/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php.Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save(): lineno 747  
proreos/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Entity.php.Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity->save(): lineno 358    
proreos/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityForm.php.Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityForm->save(): lineno 283    
proreos/proreos/src/Form/ProreosEntityFormBase.php.Drupal\proreos\Form\ProreosEntityFormBase->save(): lineno 81
```

Going backward from that I found that EntityStorageBase is setting that dirty original right before it calls the Entity's preSave method.

So, the correct approach to do it without a hook in my EntityBase is this:

```
  public function preSave(EntityStorageInterface $storage) {
       parent::preSave($storage);

       $org = $this->original;
       if ($org->isPublished() != $this->isPublished()) {
         proreos_auditinfo("Publish Status geändert, ".$this->getAuditString());
       }
  }
```

I think we should have a documented API call here in EntityInterface instead of that dirty "original" property - I'll file that as feature request at drupal.org.

Thanks. And btw. I don't like the hook system anymore because I don't like to mix that procedural approach with my OO code.